# How can I have Python read a file from my directory and print the data in columns?

Tags: python

For example
the data in my directory is a simple txt file formatted like this:

`Cat 123 123 123`

`Rat 321 321 321`

`Bat 123 123 123`

How would I go about having Python read the txt file and specifically print columns 2 and 4?

The txt file is a large amount of data. By large I mean I can't format it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to open the file to read the contents of the file and then iterate over each line, splitting the line on `space` character using `.split()` method and then simply printing the elements at the first and third position.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as data_file:
    for line in data_file.readlines():
        line = line.strip().split()
        print line[1], line[3]
```